# VisualForce - JavaScript formatting of date returned using Remote Object retrieve

Tags: visualforce, javascript, date, formatting

So using a remote object retrieve I am receiving a date in the following format:

Wed May 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

What's the best way to format this as MM/DD/YYYY using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rely on the browser here.  Using the browser assumes that your user is working on a computer set to the same timezone as the UserInfo data.  This is generally not true when you have someone working from a hotel business center a timezone away.

You can do one of two things here:

1. Create your own JavaScript method taking into account `UserInfo.getTimezone()`
2. Use these undocumented methods that are exposed in Salesforce but subject to change and not officially part of the API:

   - `DateUtil.getDateTimeStringFromUserLocale(result)` returns a string representation.
   - `DateUtil.getDateTimeFromUserLocale(value)` will read that string and turn it back into a JavaScript `Date` object, but make sure that you set the seconds and milliseconds to 0 because this method's Date result will default to whatever value `new Date()` says for those fields.

Note also, either way, before you **write a date** that there is a bug in VF Remoting:

> VFRemoting demands datetimes to be in UTC.  You cannot include an offset.
>
> Erroneous details are in VFRemote.js: VFExt3.util.JSON.encodeDate which
>   neglects to append the timezone offset of a javascript Date.

So to write a date using VF Remoting, please make sure to do the following before you write to the database:

```
  var adjustTime = function (time) {
    if (time) {
      var newTime = new Date(time);
      newTime.setMinutes(time.getMinutes()+time.getTimezoneOffset());
      return newTime;
    }
    return time;
  };
```

Comment: `DateUtil` can be found by viewing sources in Chrome `jslibrary/.../sfdc/main.js` which  says "This code is for Internal Salesforce use only, and subject to change without notice. Customers shouldn't reference this file in any web pages.". So there is a risk of Salesforce changing or removing that `DateUtil` in future releases.

Comment: @AlanMorey Yes, there are risks.  You _can_ go ahead and build a similar function that takes into account `UserInfo.getTimezone()` instead

Comment: @AlanMorey I'd also like to say that similarly, "url-hacking" is subject to change and not officially part of the API, either, but there's a LOT of infrastructure on the site that relies on both of these.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a Date value, so you can call normal Date methods on it. Use a locale-safe option that respects month/day and day/month output by having the browser figure it out for you:

```
var dateString = result.dateValue.toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: You should not call browser-locale-safe methods on Salesforce dates because those ignore your personal timezone settings in favor of the browser's settings.  If you are working a timezone away, you will run into trouble this way.